# Issue with update/modify the AD attribute from powershell

Tags: powershell

I am doing a powershell script that can update the Account Expires field in the AD based on `sAMAccoutname` but i faced some issue on `Set-ADUser` powershell command when it tried to update the Account Expires field in AD. I tested several way with various combination of command option but none of them work as expected 
**1st attempt**

```
 Set-ADUser -Identity xxxx00242 -accountExpires 130618739743580353
```

**Error received**

```
 Set-ADUser : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'accountExpires'.
    At line:1 char:31
    + Set-ADUser -Identity xxxx0242 -accountExpires 130618739743580353
    +                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

**2nd attempt**

```
Set-ADUser -identity xxxx0242 -Add @{accountExpires=" 130612691742815904"}
```

**Error Received**

```
Set-ADUser : The parameter is incorrect
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-ADUser -identity xxxx0242 -Add @{accountExpires=" 130612691742815 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (xxxx0242:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ADInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryServer:87,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.SetADUser
```

**3rd attempt**

```
 Set-ADUser -identity xxxx0242 -Add @{AccountExpirationDate=" 130612691742815904"}
```

**Error Received**

```
Set-ADUser : The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist
Parameter name: AccountExpirationDate
At line:1 char:1
+ Set-ADUser -identity xxxx0242 -Add @{AccountExpirationDate=" 13061269 ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (xxxx0242:ADUser) [Set-ADUser], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Comm
   ands.SetADUser
```

my powershell version is 5.1.14393.206 or Set-ADUser cant update Account Expires field in AD?This is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/ee617215(v=technet.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to input a valid datetime.

For instance if you want to let the account expire in 1 month.

```
$date = Get-Date
$dateExpiry = $date.AddMonths(1)
Set-ADUser xxxx0242 -AccountExpirationDate $dateExpiry
```

Please note that the returned int64 value can easily be converted to a usable datetime for instance to add 6 months to it:

```
$currentExpiry = (Get-ADUser xxxx0242 -Properties AccountExpires).accountExpires
[datetime]$expireDate = $currentExpiry
$newExpireDate = $expireDate.AddMonths(6)
Set-ADUser xxxx0242 -AccountExpirationDate $newExpireDate
```

Hope this helps!